# Text scaling properly on different mdpi devices with different resolutions

Tags: android, text, android-layout, scaling

I've started work to get my games to scale nicely on the higher-res displays like the Xoom and Galaxy Tab 10.1.

I've made use of the ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi folder naming convention for my resources which works nicely for layouts and graphics, but not so much for text size scaling.  The problem is that an Evo and a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (for example) are both mdpi devices and will map to the same layout file.  Yet, I need to scale the text size for some of my TextViews differently for these two devices.  For the record, I'm using dp for the text size units.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

- Mike

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sp for text sizes.

Apply different layouts based on screen *size* (not screen density), as described at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.